# Disable web application in specific domains

Tags: apache, web-applications, subdomain, proxypass

I have a VPS (with Debian 8) on ovh with 3 domains: (I manage them with plesk 12.5.30)

- domain1.com
- domain2.com
- domain3.com

I installed sinusbot application (https://www.sinusbot.com/) with port 1111 and then I can open it simply entering:

- domain1.com:1111
- domain2.com:1111
- domain3.com:1111
- etc... (any other domain/subdomain)

**How can I do to do this? (see below)**

- domain1.com:1111 -> return 404
- domain2.com:1111 -> return 404
- domain3.com:1111 -> return 404
- any other domain/subdomain --> return 404

**Except this:**

- sinusbot.domain1.com -> return sinusbot site

I added this:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:1111/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:1111/
```

sinusbot.domain1.com work perfectly but other domains still works...

Comment: Why don't you just define a virtualhost for each and just define the proxypass directives under the specific virtualhost where you want them working? VirtualHost directives are made specifically for these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved in this way:

**Http directives:**

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:1111/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:1111/
```

**Sinusbot config:**

```
ListenHost="localhost"
```